# WCF : Client > Endpoint > Error : Invalid URI on working URL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am setting up a WCF Selfhosted solution to use as a WCF Router and am having a little trouble in getting the service started.

The application code is

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ServiceHost routingHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RoutingService));
        routingHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Routing Service is running");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();

        routingHost.Close();

    }
}
```

and the App.Config Services Section is

```
<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8009/proposalRouter"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" 
              name="proposalRouter" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <routing filterTableName="proposalRoutingTable" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding sendTimeout="00:45:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" />
  </netTcpBinding> 
</bindings>

<routing>
  <filters>
    <filter name="proposalFilter" filterType="EndpointAddress" filterData="proposalRouter"/>
  </filters>
  <filterTables>
    <filterTable name="proposalRoutingTable">
      <add filterName="proposalFilter" endpointName="defaultProposalService"/>
    </filterTable>
  </filterTables>
</routing>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:64434/ProposalService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="*"
            name="defaultProposalService"/>
</client>
```

The error given is :

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

The issue I have narrowed down to client > endpoint but that is the uri of the svc do not sure what the issue is

I would be grateful if someone could show me where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter in your configuration file is wrong. When the value of filtertype is address, the filterdata should be a URI.

[image]

So your filter should look like this:

```
    <filters>
            <filter name="proposalFilter" filterType="EndpointAddress" filterData="net.tcp://localhost:8009/proposalRouter"/>
    </filters>
```

For more information about FilterData Property,Please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.routing.configuration.filterelement.filterdata?view=netframework-4.8